# Retrieving data from secure website on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8, webclient

I am trying to retrieve data from an authorization-restricted database which only contains text to my Windows Phone 8 app. My code looks like this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.siteaddress.com"));
}

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.Result;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following message. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance.
http://s30.postimg.org/yuc0mcb5t/pic.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send data to the server to receive response from the server, then you mean POST data to server .

```
void GetPosts(string UserID)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        Uri uristring = new Uri("somelink.com");
        webclient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postJsonData = string.Empty;
        postJsonData += "userId=" + UserID;//parameters you want to POST
        webclient.UploadStringAsync(uristring, "POST", postJsonData);
        webclient.UploadStringCompleted += webclient_UploadStringCompleted;
    }

    void webclient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        .... // any code
    }
```

Comment: I actually don't want to upload any string. Upon entering the website, it prompts you to enter a set username and password. Then it opens a single page with a long wall of text. I want my app to log in to the website, enter a predefined username and password, then copy (=download from website -> to app) the entire wall of text into a string.

Comment: This will help you to make the login progress then at the upload string completed you'll get the server's response. Just give it a try